# Get value of button inside TD datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

See the following HTML:
[image]

i need to get the value (417762) of this button. I"m trying to do it like this but it doesn't work (see the else clause beneath). I get "undefined" all the time.

```
$('#migrationssearchtable tbody').on('click',
            'td.details-control',
            function() {
                var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                var row = table.row(tr);

                if (row.child.isShown()) {
                    row.child.hide();
                    tr.removeClass('shown');
                }
                else {

                    var v = tr.find(".details-control"); // this finds the HTML of the TD
                    var o = v.find(".btn btn-requeue"); // this does not work, gives undefined.  


                }
            }
        );
```

Comment: `click` on `tbody`?

Comment: missing `.` in last selector should be `.btn.btn-requeue`

Comment: @Mr.x, it dynamically click using `on` method.

Comment: var o = v.find(".btn-requeue");

Comment: fix this `class=" details-control"` => `class="details-control"`

Comment: @Mr.x yes, using datatables like this:https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

Comment: @TemaniAfif & Faraz PV thanks that did the job! if someone posts as answer I will accept it

Comment: Also i think `$(document).on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {` is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
var o = v.find(".btn btn-requeue");
```

With

```
var o = v.find(".btn.btn-requeue");
```

You can check the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/rgs5a1xy/5/

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `v.find(".btn btn-requeue");`. Notice that `btn-requeue` has not got a period in front of it. That means it jQuery will be looking for an element with a `btn-requeue`tag inside of the element with the `btn`class.

The correct way would be `.btn.btn-requeue`, or just `.btn-requeue`.

I've changed it to  `v.find(".btn.btn-requeue");` in the code below, and that seems to do the trick.

```js
$(function(){

 $('#migrationssearchtable tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control',function() {
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
   var v = tr.find(".details-control"); // this finds the HTML of the TD

   var o = v.find(".btn.btn-requeue"); 
   alert('the value is: '+o.val());
  });
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="migrationssearchtable">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td class="details-control">
    <button class="btn btn-requeue" value="417762">
    ++
    </button>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```